# How to use nginx point to different applications while using the same domain

Tags: nginx, cakephp

I have 2 cakephp applications: one is using cake 2 and the other is using cake 3.

This is my nginx config

```
server {
        listen 80;
        client_max_body_size 2M;
        server_name cake.dev;
        root /var/virtual/cake2app/webroot;
        location /cake3-app/ {
                alias /var/virtual/cake3app/webroot;
        }

        access_log /var/log/nginx/cakephpsite.com-access.log;
        include common.conf;
        include cakephp.conf;
}
```

This is common.conf

```
index index.html;

location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
}
sendfile off;
```

This is cakephp.conf

```
include php.conf;

location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$uri&$args;
        expires max;
        access_log off;
}
```

This is php.conf

```
location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        include fastcgi_params;
}

index index.php;
```

the `cake.dev` is correctly pointing to my cake 2 app.

I cannot get cake.dev/cake3-app to point to the cake 3 app.

Inside my cake 3 app, I have a `users/login` action which works perfectly if I access the cake 3 from a separate domain.

But that is not what I want.

What have I done wrong in terms of the nginx config?

My error is consistently a 403 if I access `cake.dev/cake3-app/` and I get a cake error message telling me there is no such controller when I access `cake.dev/cake3-app`.

Please advise.

**EDIT:**

I manage to use this trick. Inside my `cakedev.conf`

I wrote

```
server {
        listen 80;
        client_max_body_size 2M;
        server_name cake.dev;
        root /var/virtual/cake2/webroot;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/cakephpsite.com-access.log;
        include common.conf;
        include cakephp.conf;
        location /cake3-app/ {
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header HOST $http_host;
                proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:83;
                proxy_redirect off;
                rewrite ^/cake3-app/(.*)$ /$1 break;
        }
}
```

Then I have a `cake3.conf`

```
server {
        listen 83;
        client_max_body_size 2M;
        server_name 127.0.0.1;
        root /var/virtual/cake3/webroot;
        include common.conf;
        include cakephp.conf;
}
```

The url redirect works for the web pages but **NOT** the various assets of the cake3 app.

Cake3App auto points to `http://cake.dev/css/base.css` when it should be pointing to `http://cake.dev/cake3/css/base.css`

Perhaps I need to write something different for the `common.conf` and the `cakephp.conf` for the `cake3.conf`?

Comment: Why use proxy pass at all? You could just as easily do `location /cake3-app { root /var/virtual/cake3/webroot; ... }`

Comment: i tried that before and it didn't work for some reason. Let me try again. I think it didn't work because I needed to do the rewrite so I can reuse common.conf and cakephp.conf

Comment: Yup it didn't work. I got a 404

Comment: in my last line, i did write 'Perhaps I need to write something different for the common.conf and the cakephp.conf for the cake3.conf?' So I supposed you are referring to this. I am not particularly clear about how to rewrite teh cakephp.conf for this use case. By the way, the common.conf, cakephp.conf, and php.conf setup was taught to me by the CakeDC people, (graham weldon I think) a few years ago when I hired their help. Be happy to rewrite the configurations if you could show me how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 3 steps. First 2 are nginx-related. Last one is cakephp-related.

**Step 1: Need to inform the config responsible for server_name http://cake.dev to redirect http://cake.dev/cake3 urls to the right config**

Assuming `cakedev.conf` is the config responsible for `http://cake.dev`

```
server {
        listen 80;
        client_max_body_size 2M;
        server_name cake.dev;
        root /var/virtual/cake2/webroot;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/cakephpsite.com-access.log;
        include common.conf;
        include cakephp.conf;
        location /cake3-app/ {
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header HOST $http_host;
                proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:83;
                proxy_redirect off;
                rewrite ^/cake3-app/(.*)$ /$1 break;
        }
}
```

Notice how I write the `proxy_pass`? It goes to `127.0.0.1:83`. This is crucial though I suspect you can  change the port number.

**Step 2: Write up the config responsible for cake3**

Assuming the file is cake3.conf

```
server {
        listen 83;
        client_max_body_size 2M;
        server_name 127.0.0.1;
        root /var/virtual/cake3/webroot;
        include common.conf;
        include cakephp.conf;
}
```

Notice how the server_name and the listen matches with the proxy_pass from the earlier config? This is crucial.

**Step 3: Change the `App.base` inside cake3**

Go inside your cake 3 app and look for config/app.php

Change this value

```
'App' => [
    'namespace' => 'App',
    'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
    'base' => false,
```

to

```
'App' => [
    'namespace' => 'App',
    'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
    'base' => '/cake3-app', // please make sure you start with a / and NEVER end with a /
```

Comment: Is this still valid in 2023?